# Partial<SomeClass> but without methods?

Tags: typescript

I'll often make a class with a constructor that can take any arbitrary members that are appropriate to the class:

```js
class SomeClass {
  propA: string;
  propB: number;

  constructor(obj: Partial<SomeClass>) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => this[key] = obj[key]);
  }
}
```

So then I can do `new SomeObject({propA: 'whatever'})` or `new SomeObject({propB: 3})` or any combination (obviously this is more useful when there are more properties.

(Assume this is a low-stakes personal project and we can ignore whatever reasons there might be for not writing a constructor like this.)

So, this is great, and it also means Intellisense will show me the options as I construct a new instance of the class.

However, that Intellisense list also includes the methods of the class (although my example doesn't have any methods, I think you get the idea).

Is there a variant or constraint for `Partial<SomeClass>` that will only allow properties? And since I often use arrow functions, I guess they would be properties that aren't functions (since I think arrow functions are technically properties not methods).

Answer (score 4):

You can use a mapped + conditional type get the keys that are not functions with something like:

```
type NonMethodKeys<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? never : K
}[keyof T]
```

This goes through all object keys, and if it's a function, it sets the property type to `never`, else whatever the key `K` is. Then you index it by `[keyof T]` which returns all values that are non `never`. This gives you a union of property names that not functions.

Then you can simply `Pick` those keys from a type.

```
type WithoutMethods<T> = Pick<T, NonMethodKeys<T>>
```

And then use it like so:

```
type A = WithoutMethods<{ a(): number, b: string}> // type: { b: string }
```

Or in your case:

```
constructor(obj: Partial<WithoutMethods<SomeClass>>) { /* ... */ }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gOwLIWACzgEwNIRAZwB4AVAPigF4oBvAKCgagG1soBLBKAazzgDMoxALoAuQSyFQIAD2AQEmfFABiAVwQBjYG0RQA-FAQQAbhABOUMdloBfJjxD9BQ2rVCQoAdTbo4q4Ci+iiTkVAAKbBpcJAA0sIiBGDh4RGSkru7QAIKUXj4Y-olYRNRQAIYAFACUYgiqALYARuZxjWL4wGYcAOY25AD0-VCZYqVtUB1dCN1QNkA)

---

In typescript 4.1 (unreleased, currently in beta), this gets a little easier with [Key Remapping in Mapped Types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1-beta/#key-remapping-mapped-types) and an `as` clause of the mapped key. By mapping the key to `never`, it's omitted.

```
type WithoutMethods<T> = {
    [K in keyof T as
        T[K] extends Function ? never : K
    ]: T[K]
}

type A = WithoutMethods<{ a(): number, b: string}> // type: { b: string }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20201015#code/C4TwDgpgBA6glsAFgewK7ALIScgJgZwB4AVAPigF4oBvAKCgagG0BpKOAOygGsIRkAZlGJQAhvnqMpxVgF0oEAB7AIHAlABiqDgGNgcZFwD8UDhABuEAE5QAXFBaSGs+zJazaAX1q1QkKACClLAIKOhYOASE1GIAFACU9hyoALYARtYANFBp9vjAVpwA5p7kAPRlUH4Q9jG5UPmFHEVQnkA)